# hex2chars & chars2hex functions

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a function hex2chars:

```
def hex2chars(data):
    result = ''.join(chr(int(data[i:i + 2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(data), 2))
    return result

data = '9ede820b31ae92d83be578a7ab8ce906c4ead38943ee73a36e058fac33a0a85861ec46f9cf1ec3d11c0ec8b14aea470c37c1eb87375aca94d9b214e90a0b73f8214d929675768c3d88c95b5618438685ec99cf50ccd846902be6104335482c1ae0136f2dfcfd97e072c38c8d142c9f92f25f3b911bac5beaa51184eb1e6c3169b3b58ec8e094b988648136f6b4bde59def0bce7f03e0cf321f95d067e3319f31dd099513c0d7'
```

How I can create a chars2hex function?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please make sure that the code that you place in your question is runnable. In your case, the indentation was bad. I'll edit that, but in the future please avoid this situation. Also, do you have any ideas on your problem, any attempted code? You should also make it clear what data format you want for your input and your output: there are several possible for this problem. Your line `data =` is not correct Python code.

Comment: data it is string

Comment: mohammad, when i use int(chars,16) i see ValueError, chars it is result of function hex2chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse conversion is easy. You just need to use `ord`, the inverse function of `chr`, and format the result to 2 digit hexadecimal:

```
def hex2chars(data):
    return ''.join([chr(int(data[i:i + 2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)])

def chars2hex(data):
    return ''.join(['%02x' % ord(c) for c in data])

data = '9ede820b31ae92d83be578a7ab8ce906c4ead38943ee73a36e058fac33a0a85861ec46f9cf1ec3d11c0ec8b14aea470c37c1eb87375aca94d9b214e90a0b73f8214d929675768c3d88c95b5618438685ec99cf50ccd846902be6104335482c1ae0136f2dfcfd97e072c38c8d142c9f92f25f3b911bac5beaa51184eb1e6c3169b3b58ec8e094b988648136f6b4bde59def0bce7f03e0cf321f95d067e3319f31dd099513c0d7'

s = hex2chars(data)
new_data = chars2hex(s)
print data == new_data
```

**output**

```
True
```

Note that you need to use a different approach in Python 3.

However, there's no need to code these functions yourself: you can use the functions in the standard [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) module to write code that will work correctly on Python 2 or Python 3.